# How does the Bias parameter adjusts Chebyshev nodes in RationalInterpolation of the Function Approximation Package?

Tags: special-functions, number-representation, approximation

How does the Bias parameter adjusts Chebyshev nodes in RationalInterpolation of the Function Approximation Package? What is the mathematical mapping/formula applied in the Bias adjustment from -1 1 for the Chebyshev nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inspect the (well-commented) code with:

```
NotebookOpen[
 FileNameJoin[{DirectoryName@
    FindFile["FunctionApproximations`FunctionApproximations`"], 
   "Approximations.m"}]]
```

Search for "`RI[f`" (or "`GRI[f`") and find the following line to see how `Bias` is implemented:

```
xx += bias (1 - xx xx);
```

(The variable `xx` is the array of Chebyshev nodes.)